# UUIDs of iBeacons are different on different devices

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ibeacon, indoor-positioning-system

I'm developing an application that will use iBeacons for indoor navigation, and I found that the rate the function `locationManager:rangingBeaconsDidFailForRegion:withError:` is being called is not high enough, so I'm going to add the RSSI data from CoreBluetooth's `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:`.

And I found a curious fact: when I listen to the iBeacon with CoreLocation and log the peripheral id:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central 
    didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral 
    advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData 
    RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"%@, RSSI: %@", peripheral, RSSI);
```

each beacon is reported with different UUID on different devices:

```
A25804BD-D77A-5004-4C2C-301D996C7367 - my iPhone 5
843F4237-6059-9A5E-AA34-0BD92304BE1F - colleague's iPhone 5
77685805-C253-52BD-B787-8B95308834FB - other colleague's iPad mini
```

The idea was to bind UUID of each beacon to its location, so this behavior is quite functionality-breaking.

Why the UUID of physically the same beacon (not powered off/on) is different on different devices? Is it an expected behavior? If it is, how could I opt out of it?

Comment: Counterintuitively, you cannot see the iBeacon UUID with core bluetooth, what you see instead is a stand in identifier assigned by the bluetooth stack of the receiving phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot read the identifiers of standard iBeacons using `CoreBluetooth`.  As Chris Stratton said in his comment, the UUID that CoreBluetooth gives you is a device UUID, which is randomly generated on a per-session basis by iOS.  It has nothing to do with the iBeacon ProximityUUID.

More details on why you can't read iBeacon identifiers with `CoreBluetooth` are here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

It is true that you only get on RSSI measurement per `locationManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:` callback.  This is a real obstacle to doing a custom distance estimate.  Behind the scenes, iOS can gather 10x as many measurements for iBeacons transmitting at 10Hz.  You are correct that you can get more measurements using `CoreBluetooth`, but the problem is that there is no reliable way of lining up which bluetooth devices you see with `CoreBluetooth` correspond to the iBeacons you can see with `CoreLocation`.